# tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model error: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow

Objective:

I am trying to save my model in a .pb or .pbtxt format using `tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, saved_model_dir)` as described in the following tutorial:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/data-science-on-gcp/blob/master/updates/cloudml/flights_model_tf2.ipynb

I get the error:

```
init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

The code is below:

```
training_history = model.fit(train_ds, 
                    validation_data=val_ds,
                    epochs=epochs, 
                    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(patience=patience), tensorboard_callback ])

now=str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':','_').replace(' ','_').replace('.','_')

saved_model_dir="saved_models/"+now

tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, saved_model_dir)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'
```

Comment: while you using keras, my recommendation is to save it in .h5 file, it's easier to save and restore.

Comment: the reason I need to store it .pb or .pbtxt is to be able to use ti on the google cloud.